# Ball Trajectory end position calculation

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, projectile

From the image, from bounce position, i want to predict position p1, p2 or p3 using some angle theta 1, 2 or 3.

How can i achieve this.

Any help please.

[image]

thanks

**Edit:**

I am trying to implement bowling control of Cricket.
To show the bowling trajectory, i need three points

start position, bounce position and end position

Start Position = the ball position where bowler releases ball from his hand.
Bounce Position = the pitching position of ball in front of batsman 
End position = behind the stump (this will be calculated on the basis of swing i.e in swing or out swing or spin)

So my question is, i know the start position of ball, bounce position of the ball and i know the swing angle by which my ball is supposed to swing.

i need to calculated the end position of the ball by this.

i hope i make it clear now.

Comment: O_o. What is θ1, θ2 and θ3?

Comment: And what is criteria for selecting between them? Also, what unity3d has to do with all these? Please update your question so that it is clear what your problem is

Comment: This question is absolutely confusing now. Can you explain the situation, what exactly are you trying to predict?

Comment: question is edited now. added more description.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just basic trig.  Using p1 for example, you know c_x, c_y, b_x, b_y. b_x and c_y make d.  subtraction gets you hard numbers.
So theta_1 is the inverse tangent of b -> d divided by d -> c (sohcahTOA!).  In a unit circle the tangent theta_1 becomes Y/X.

[see diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP1iE.jpg)

I have no idea how to play cricket though.  I know it uses a flat(ish?) bat.  If you want to analyse the effect of a batters swing, that gets more complicated.

Comment: Further, if you want to know theta_2, you just need to consider that theta_1*2+theta_2*2=360 (or 2*pi), basic algebra gets you the rest of the way.  Hope this all helped.